# Android code to stop thread service running in back ground

Tags: android, multithreading, service

Hi here is the code to run the service in back ground. It is working fine. But it is not getting stopped when operation is finished. Here is my code. I am unable to stop service once data is sent to server and i am calling delete method to delete data in sqlite and mythread.stop(); to stop thread but it is not getting stopped. who to stop thread is there any solution for that.

```
public class ServiceTest extends Service {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String timerss=null,additional=null;

    String loc=null;

    int localUname = 0;

    String sno;

    String deviceid;

    List<Contact> contacts;

    private static String TAG = ServiceTest.class.getSimpleName();
    private MyThread mythread;
    public boolean isRunning = false;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        mythread  = new MyThread();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if(!isRunning){
            mythread.interrupt();
            mythread.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        if(!isRunning){
            mythread.start();
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }

    public void readWebPage(){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ServiceTest.this);
        contacts = db.getAllContacts();
        for (Contact cn : contacts) {
            String log = " USERNAME: "
                    + cn.getID() + " ,loc: " +cn.getName();

            localUname =  cn.getID();
            sno = String.valueOf(localUname);
            loc = cn.getName();
            timerss = cn.getPhoneNumber();
//          deviceid = cn.getMacId();
//          additional = cn.getAdditonal();

            System.out.println("benbenarji:" + localUname + loc+timerss+deviceid+additional);

            System.out.println("benbenarji1:" + localUname + loc);

        }
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ip:80808/ActIotWifiLockApp/LockWebServices/storeLogForUD");
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("slno", sno));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("macId", deviceid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("logdesc", additional));
            System.out.println("logdes:" + additional);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateTime", "timerss"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "loc"));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            System.out.println("ResponseScan: " + response);

//            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//                public void run() {
//
//                    dialog.dismiss();
//                }
//            });

            if (response.contains("true")) {

                db.deleteAllData();
                mythread.interrupt();
                mythread.stop();

            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread{
        static final long DELAY = 10000;
        @Override
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("ben:"+isRunning);
            while(isRunning){
                Log.d(TAG,"Running");
                try {
                    readWebPage();
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    isRunning = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `onDestry` contains the line

```
if(!isRunning){
```

Could it be that you need to say:

```
if(isRunning){
```

because I assume you want to stop the thread if `isRunning` is `true`.

Besides this, the documentation reminds us of the following:

> it is your responsibility to stop the service when its work is done, by calling stopSelf() or stopService().